# How to change value of element in array in for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have the following array :

```
for (let i of lastBal) {
    var amtToDetect = received_amt;

    console.log('amt to detect', amtToDetect);

    var lpcForLoop = i.lpc;
    var lic_fee_for_loop = i.lic_fee;
    var daysDifference_for_loop = i.lpdays;
    var onlineLPC_for_loop = i.onlinelpc;
    var total_amt_for_loop = i.total_amt;

    console.log('lic fee for loop', i.lic_fee);

    if (amtToDetect >= lic_fee_for_loop) {
        var remainAmtAfterLPC = Math.floor(amtToDetect - lpcForLoop);
        var paidLPC = amtToDetect - remainAmtAfterLPC;

        if (remainAmtAfterLPC > 0) {
            if (remainAmtAfterLPC >= lic_fee_for_loop) {
                var remainBalanceAfterLicFee = remainAmtAfterLPC - lic_fee_for_loop
                var paidLicFee = remainAmtAfterLPC - remainBalanceAfterLicFee;
                var total_amt_payment = Math.floor(paidLicFee + lpcForLoop);

                //for balance entry
                var bal_lic_fee = Math.floor(lic_fee_for_loop - paidLicFee);
                var bal_LPC = Math.floor(lpcForLoop - lpcForLoop);
                var bal_total_amt = Math.floor(bal_lic_fee + bal_LPC);
            }
        }

    }

    //console.log('demand in for loop',demandInsertData);

    let difference = paymentDate - lic_fee_due_date;
    var daysDifference = Math.floor(difference / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
    var onlineLPC = Math.floor(lic_fee * 0.18 * daysDifference / 365);
    var currentLPC = Math.floor(onlineLPC + bal_LPC);
    var total_amt = Math.floor(lic_fee + currentLPC);

    console.log('in end for loop');

    i.lpc = onlineLPC;
    i.lic_fee = lic_fee - i.lic_fee;

    console.log('in end for loop lic fee', i.lic_fee);

    i.lpdays = daysDifference;
    i.total_amt = total_amt;
    received_amt = remainBalanceAfterLicFee;

    console.log('in end for loop received_amt', received_amt);
}
```

In the above for loop, I want to replace some elements from `lastBal` array.

At the end of the for loop, I tried to replace some elements as follows :

```
i.lic_fee = lic_fee - i.lic_fee;
```

However, values are not being replaced during the next iteration. Instead, old values are being assigned.

How can I find the issue here?

### Edit

After changing elements values I want to use them in same for loop.
Means after 1st iteration in for loop I want to change the values of element and use the updated values in next iteration.

Here at end of loop values are updated, but in second iteration old values form lastBal are assign.

### Edit 2: Added lastBal

```
last bal [ RowDataPacket {
demand_id: 42,
user_id: 4,
lic_id: 4,
description: 'Balance',
demand_start_date: '2020-07-01',
demand_end_date: '2020-09-30',
demand_fin_year: '2020-2021',
lic_fee: 27000,
form_fee: 0,
lic_fee_due_date: '2020-06-30',
lrc: 0,
srtax: 0,
lpc: 1224,
total_amt: 28224,
outstanding_amt: 28224,
lpdays: 92,
onlinelpc: 1224,
flag: 0,
lic_fee_pay_id: 0,
demand_added_date: '2020-04-28 19:43:14',
payment_date: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' },
RowDataPacket {
demand_id: 44,
user_id: 4,
lic_id: 4,
description: 'Balance',
demand_start_date: '2020-10-01',
demand_end_date: '2020-12-31',
demand_fin_year: '2020-2021',
lic_fee: 54000,
form_fee: 0,
lic_fee_due_date: '2020-09-30',
lrc: 0,
srtax: 0,
lpc: 1224,
total_amt: 55224,
outstanding_amt: 55224,
lpdays: 0,
onlinelpc: 0,
flag: 0,
lic_fee_pay_id: 0,
demand_added_date: '2020-04-28 19:52:25',
payment_date: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' } ]
```

Above array is fetch from database.I want to updated 2nd RowDataPacket after 1st iteration in for loop.values to updated 2nd RowDataPacket are dynamic.

Comment: I notice one thing: In the assignment of `received_amt` you are accessing `remainBalanceAfterLicFee` which is not assigned in every iteration because it's inside your `if`! The fact that you are using `var` instead of `let` (or in this case even better `const` because you assign it only once anyway) masks this issue due to automatic variable hoisting.

Comment: Can you `console.log` your `lastBal` before and after this loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I did try to reproduce with your code while putting some sample values in the fields wherever necessay and I do see the expected modifications. Hence, you need to clarify where exactly you're not seeing the changes that you're expecting.

```
     var lastBal = [{ lpc: 1, lic_fee: 2, lpdays: 9, onlinelpc: 4, total_amt: 2 }, { lpc: 3, lic_fee: 4, lpdays: 2, onlinelpc: 5, total_amt: 1 }];
var editedValues = {};
for (let i of lastBal) {
    if (!(Object.keys(editedValues).length === 0 && editedValues.constructor === Object)) {
        i = {...i, ...editedValues} ;
    }
    var amtToDetect = 5;
    console.log('amt to detect', amtToDetect);
    var lpcForLoop = i.lpc;
    var lic_fee_for_loop = i.lic_fee;
    var daysDifference_for_loop = i.lpdays;
    var onlineLPC_for_loop = i.onlinelpc;
    var total_amt_for_loop = i.total_amt;
    console.log('lic fee for loop', i.lic_fee);
    if (amtToDetect >= lic_fee_for_loop) {
        var remainAmtAfterLPC = Math.floor(amtToDetect - lpcForLoop);
        var paidLPC = amtToDetect - remainAmtAfterLPC;
        if (remainAmtAfterLPC > 0) {
            if (remainAmtAfterLPC >= lic_fee_for_loop) {
                var remainBalanceAfterLicFee = remainAmtAfterLPC - lic_fee_for_loop
                var paidLicFee = remainAmtAfterLPC - remainBalanceAfterLicFee;
                var total_amt_payment = Math.floor(paidLicFee + lpcForLoop);
                //for balance entry
                var bal_lic_fee = Math.floor(lic_fee_for_loop - paidLicFee);
                var bal_LPC = Math.floor(lpcForLoop - lpcForLoop);
                var bal_total_amt = Math.floor(bal_lic_fee + bal_LPC);
            }
        }

    }
    //console.log('demand in for loop',demandInsertData);
    var daysDifference = 5000;
    var onlineLPC = 2000;
    var currentLPC = 1000;
    var total_amt = 1500;
    console.log('in end for loop');
    i.lpc = onlineLPC;
    i.lic_fee = 4000 - i.lic_fee;
    console.log('in end for loop lic fee', i.lic_fee);
    i.lpdays = daysDifference;
    i.total_amt = 7000;
    received_amt = 11000;
    console.log('in end for loop received_amt', received_amt);
    editedValues = {
        pc: onlineLPC,
        lic_fee: lic_fee - i.lic_fee,
        lpdays: daysDifference,
        total_amt: total_amt,
        onlinelpc: onlineLPC,
        received_amt: remainBalanceAfterLicFee
    } // Whatever values you'd like to retain for the subsequent execution
}
console.log(lastBal);
```

**EDIT**
- Updated accordingly as you updated your requirements.

Comment: thank u for your answer,please see i have edit my question

Comment: @sangRam Well, how can you find the previous iteration results in the next iteration while the execution is still going on? say `arr[0]` is updated then control moves towards `arr[1]`. So what exactly do you wish to find in `arr[1]`? Maybe you're not doing it in the right way? so can you just post the exact `input` and `output` that you'd like to receive?

Comment: after arr[0] is updated, i want same updated values in arr[1]..

Comment: So what you're saying is this: as soon as `arr[0]` gets updated, we should update all of the remaining items in the array with the same values? There's a better way to solve this. Post an expected sample of `lastBal` before and after this loop.

Comment: yes, all values should be update after arr[0] and so on.

Comment: please check i have added lastBal array which is fetch from database

Comment: Ok in that case see the updated answer above. I created `editedValues` as an empty object and assigned in the fist execution. Later when once it's 'filled' the values will be coming from this for the subsequent executions. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213455/discussion-between-sangram-and-rahul-dwivedi).

Answer (score -1):

Because you are not accessing the array index/key, or in this case the object in javascript. 
Take a look at the code below, I can't change "b to bb" assigning "bb" to the variable **display the value** in the for loop (key). In this case key='bb' will print the value but it will not change it.

```
var test = [];
test = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'];
for (let key of test){
    if (key == 'b') { key = 'bb'}
 console.log(key);
}
test[1] = 'cc';
for (let key of test){
 console.log(key);
}
```

In order to change the value in the object/array you need to reference the index/key from the original array. **test[1]='cc';** then the value will be changed.

Run the code commenting the **test[1]='cc';** line, you will see that the value was not change in the initial loop, then run it uncommenting the line.

Comment: This is true if the OP were to change the element reference itself, but they wrote they are writing to _properties_ of the elements, which is fine.